# Node App works on Heroku Local but crashes on Heroku server. using simple Foundation template project

Tags: node.js, heroku, gulp, zurb-foundation, package.json

I am trying to deploy a Foundation web app based on Yarn, Gulp and Node.js on Heroku. It works with `heroku local web` but crashes on the Heroku server.

I have set the port correctly. I am trying to remove Browsersync and use gulp-connect instead. In my `gulpfile.js` I have set the `connectHeroku` task which is run after build. I have set the `yarn start` command in the environment for Heroku.

Here is my `gulp.babel.js`:

```
'use strict';

import plugins       from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import yargs         from 'yargs';
import browser       from 'browser-sync';
import gulp          from 'gulp';
import panini        from 'panini';
import rimraf        from 'rimraf';
import sherpa        from 'style-sherpa';
import yaml          from 'js-yaml';
import fs            from 'fs';
import webpackStream from 'webpack-stream';
import webpack2      from 'webpack';
import named         from 'vinyl-named';
import uncss         from 'uncss';
import autoprefixer  from 'autoprefixer';
import gulpConnect   from 'gulp-connect';

// Load all Gulp plugins into one variable
const $ = plugins();

// Check for --production flag
const PRODUCTION = !!(yargs.argv.production);

// Load settings from config.yml
const { COMPATIBILITY, PORT, UNCSS_OPTIONS, PATHS } = loadConfig();

function loadConfig() {
  let ymlFile = fs.readFileSync('config.yml', 'utf8');
  return yaml.load(ymlFile);
}

// Build the "dist" folder by running all of the below tasks
// Sass must be run later so UnCSS can search for used classes in the others assets.
gulp.task('build',
 gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(pages, javascript, images, copy), sass, styleGuide));

gulp.task('connectHeroku', function () {
  gulpConnect.server({
    root: PATHS.dist,
    port: process.env.PORT || PORT
  });
});

// Build the site, run the server, and watch for file changes
gulp.task('default',gulp.series('build','connectHeroku'));
// gulp.task('default',gulp.series('build','connectHeroku'));


// gulp.task('default',
//   gulp.series('build','connectHeroku'));

// gulp.task('start','node app.js');

// gulp.task('default',
//   gulp.series('build', server, watch));

// Delete the "dist" folder
// This happens every time a build starts
function clean(done) {
  rimraf(PATHS.dist, done);
}

// Copy files out of the assets folder
// This task skips over the "img", "js", and "scss" folders, which are parsed separately
function copy() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.assets)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets'));
}

// Copy page templates into finished HTML files
function pages() {
  return gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.{html,hbs,handlebars}')
    .pipe(panini({
      root: 'src/pages/',
      layouts: 'src/layouts/',
      partials: 'src/partials/',
      data: 'src/data/',
      helpers: 'src/helpers/'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist));
}

// Load updated HTML templates and partials into Panini
function resetPages(done) {
  panini.refresh();
  done();
}

// Generate a style guide from the Markdown content and HTML template in styleguide/
function styleGuide(done) {
  sherpa('src/styleguide/index.md', {
    output: PATHS.dist + '/styleguide.html',
    template: 'src/styleguide/template.html'
  }, done);
}

// Compile Sass into CSS
// In production, the CSS is compressed
function sass() {

  const postCssPlugins = [
    // Autoprefixer
    autoprefixer({ browsers: COMPATIBILITY }),

    // UnCSS - Uncomment to remove unused styles in production
    // PRODUCTION && uncss.postcssPlugin(UNCSS_OPTIONS),
  ].filter(Boolean);

  return gulp.src('src/assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass({
      includePaths: PATHS.sass
    })
      .on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.postcss(postCssPlugins))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.cleanCss({ compatibility: 'ie9' })))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browser.reload({ stream: true }));
}

let webpackConfig = {
  mode: (PRODUCTION ? 'production' : 'development'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [ "@babel/preset-env" ],
            compact: false
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: !PRODUCTION && 'source-map'
}

// Combine JavaScript into one file
// In production, the file is minified
function javascript() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.entries)
    .pipe(named())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig, webpack2))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uglify()
      .on('error', e => { console.log(e); })
    ))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js'));
}

// Copy images to the "dist" folder
// In production, the images are compressed
function images() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/img/**/*')
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.imagemin([
      $.imagemin.jpegtran({ progressive: true }),
    ])))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/img'));
}

// Start a server with BrowserSync to preview the site in
function server(done) {

    browser.init({
      server: PATHS.dist, port: process.env.PORT || PORT, open: false
    }, done);

}

// Reload the browser with BrowserSync
function reload(done) {
  browser.reload();
  done();
}

// Watch for changes to static assets, pages, Sass, and JavaScript
function watch() {
  gulp.watch(PATHS.assets, copy);
  gulp.watch('src/pages/**/*.html').on('all', gulp.series(pages, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/{layouts,partials}/**/*.html').on('all', gulp.series(resetPages, pages, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/data/**/*.{js,json,yml}').on('all', gulp.series(resetPages, pages, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/helpers/**/*.js').on('all', gulp.series(resetPages, pages, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/assets/scss/**/*.scss').on('all', sass);
  gulp.watch('src/assets/js/**/*.js').on('all', gulp.series(javascript, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/assets/img/**/*').on('all', gulp.series(images, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/styleguide/**').on('all', gulp.series(styleGuide, browser.reload));
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Imaginary-Symposium",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Imaginary Symposium",
  "main": "gulpfile.babel.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp build --production"
  },
  "author": "ZURB <foundation@zurb.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "foundation-sites": "^6.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "motion-ui": "^2.0.3",
    "what-input": "^5.1.2",
     "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.3.1",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.7.0",
    "gulp-extname": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.7.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.4.6",
    "panini": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "style-sherpa": "^1.0.0",
    "uncss": "^0.16.2",
    "vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.1.1",
    "yargs": "^12.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.3.1",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.7.0",
    "gulp-extname": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.7.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.4.6",
    "panini": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "style-sherpa": "^1.0.0",
    "uncss": "^0.16.2",
    "vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.1.1",
    "yargs": "^12.0.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues",
    "email": "foundation@zurb.com"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x",
    "yarn": "1.16.x"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I would like to have the application deployed on Heroku.

Instead I get this:

```
2019-07-07T12:35:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2019-07-07T12:36:25.772475+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c66e2cec by user 
2019-07-07T12:36:25.772475+00:00 app[api]: Release v32 created by user 
2019-07-07T12:36:27.030070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-07T12:36:33.644558+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `yarn start`
2019-07-07T12:36:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-07-07T12:36:35.716329+00:00 app[web.1]: yarn run v1.16.0
2019-07-07T12:36:35.799780+00:00 app[web.1]: $ gulp
2019-07-07T12:36:36.286970+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:36] Requiring external module @babel/register
2019-07-07T12:36:36.708934+00:00 app[web.1]: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade caniuse-lite browserslist`
2019-07-07T12:36:39.150637+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.babel.js
2019-07-07T12:36:39.151579+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Starting 'default'...
2019-07-07T12:36:39.153676+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Starting 'build'...
2019-07-07T12:36:39.154337+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Starting 'clean'...
2019-07-07T12:36:39.163199+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Finished 'clean' after 8.42 ms
2019-07-07T12:36:39.163542+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Starting 'pages'...
2019-07-07T12:36:39.163731+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Starting 'javascript'...
2019-07-07T12:36:39.163915+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Starting 'images'...
2019-07-07T12:36:39.164097+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Starting 'copy'...
2019-07-07T12:36:39.378140+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Finished 'images' after 214 ms
2019-07-07T12:36:39.630308+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Finished 'pages' after 467 ms
2019-07-07T12:36:39.664236+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:39] Finished 'copy' after 500 ms
2019-07-07T12:36:45.584344+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:45] Version: webpack 4.25.1
2019-07-07T12:36:45.584359+00:00 app[web.1]: Built at: 07/07/2019 12:36:45 PM
2019-07-07T12:36:45.584362+00:00 app[web.1]: Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
2019-07-07T12:36:45.584364+00:00 app[web.1]: app.js   677 KiB     app  [emitted]  app
2019-07-07T12:36:45.584365+00:00 app[web.1]: app.js.map  1.05 MiB     app  [emitted]  app
2019-07-07T12:36:45.584366+00:00 app[web.1]: Entrypoint app = app.js app.js.map
2019-07-07T12:36:45.588167+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:45] Finished 'javascript' after 6.42 s
2019-07-07T12:36:45.588354+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:45] Starting 'sass'...
2019-07-07T12:36:47.313608+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:47] Finished 'sass' after 1.73 s
2019-07-07T12:36:47.313741+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:47] Starting 'styleGuide'...
2019-07-07T12:36:47.344145+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:47] Finished 'styleGuide' after 30 ms
2019-07-07T12:36:47.344291+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:47] Finished 'build' after 8.19 s
2019-07-07T12:36:47.344423+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:47] Starting 'connectHeroku'...
2019-07-07T12:36:47.345546+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:47] Starting server...
2019-07-07T12:36:47.353434+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:47] Server started http://localhost:6186
2019-07-07T12:36:47.353712+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:36:47] Running server
2019-07-07T12:37:34.179753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-07T12:37:34.252667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-07T12:37:34.069250+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-07-07T12:37:34.069434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-07-07T12:37:34.164632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-07-07T12:37:39.890453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `yarn start`
2019-07-07T12:37:42.525193+00:00 app[web.1]: yarn run v1.16.0
2019-07-07T12:37:42.605985+00:00 app[web.1]: $ gulp
2019-07-07T12:37:43.171985+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:43] Requiring external module @babel/register
2019-07-07T12:37:43.571081+00:00 app[web.1]: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade caniuse-lite browserslist`
2019-07-07T12:37:45.999600+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:45] Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.babel.js
2019-07-07T12:37:46.000576+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Starting 'default'...
2019-07-07T12:37:46.002883+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Starting 'build'...
2019-07-07T12:37:46.003508+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Starting 'clean'...
2019-07-07T12:37:46.011249+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Finished 'clean' after 7.45 ms
2019-07-07T12:37:46.011592+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Starting 'pages'...
2019-07-07T12:37:46.011777+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Starting 'javascript'...
2019-07-07T12:37:46.011956+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Starting 'images'...
2019-07-07T12:37:46.012134+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Starting 'copy'...
2019-07-07T12:37:46.222874+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Finished 'images' after 211 ms
2019-07-07T12:37:46.502195+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Finished 'pages' after 490 ms
2019-07-07T12:37:46.514761+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:46] Finished 'copy' after 503 ms
2019-07-07T12:37:53.917049+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:53] Version: webpack 4.25.1
2019-07-07T12:37:53.917059+00:00 app[web.1]: Built at: 07/07/2019 12:37:53 PM
2019-07-07T12:37:53.917062+00:00 app[web.1]: Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
2019-07-07T12:37:53.917064+00:00 app[web.1]: app.js   677 KiB     app  [emitted]  app
2019-07-07T12:37:53.917065+00:00 app[web.1]: app.js.map  1.05 MiB     app  [emitted]  app
2019-07-07T12:37:53.917066+00:00 app[web.1]: Entrypoint app = app.js app.js.map
2019-07-07T12:37:53.923691+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:53] Finished 'javascript' after 7.91 s
2019-07-07T12:37:53.923957+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:53] Starting 'sass'...
2019-07-07T12:37:55.730383+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:55] Finished 'sass' after 1.81 s
2019-07-07T12:37:55.730560+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:55] Starting 'styleGuide'...
2019-07-07T12:37:55.764813+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:55] Finished 'styleGuide' after 34 ms
2019-07-07T12:37:55.764969+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:55] Finished 'build' after 9.76 s
2019-07-07T12:37:55.765114+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:55] Starting 'connectHeroku'...
2019-07-07T12:37:55.766393+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:55] Starting server...
2019-07-07T12:37:55.777651+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:55] Server started http://localhost:10590
2019-07-07T12:37:55.778034+00:00 app[web.1]: [12:37:55] Running server
2019-07-07T12:38:39.995481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-07T12:38:39.903593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-07-07T12:38:39.903593+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-07-07T12:38:39.980831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Comment: Oh, you have everything crammed into one code listing. That's very confusing. I'll fix it. In the future, please use _separate_ code blocks, i.e. one `\`\`\`` block or indented block per file.

Comment: And either indent your code blocks _or_ use a fenced code block with `\`\`\``, not both.

Comment: It looks like `gulp-connect` is for development use only: "Gulp plugin to run a webserver (with LiveReload)". There's no reason to use LiveReload in production. Where's your production configuration, e.g. with Express or similar?

Comment: many thanks Chris! Really appreciate it. Actually am quite new to this and am not sure what I have to do to for a production configuration. :/ Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really a Node.js guy, but I think you want Express. You might want to check out [Heroku's getting started with Node.js guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs).

Comment: many thanks @Chris! Will look into it.

Comment: Have just posted as an answer what worked for me. Many thanks @Chris for pointing out the usage of Expressjs. Am fairly new to all this and learning how things work. I have successfully deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here is what I've managed to do and it worked (pls note that I am very new to this):
**Stack**: Zurb Foundation template ([zurb foundation](https://zurb.foundation.com)) which uses yarn and gulp for packet management and build. Outputs to a folder called dist (changeable in the config.yml); Expressjs; NodeJS.

```
Code follows after the steps.
```

1. Used @Chris comment above on using Expressjs ([expressjs.com](https://expressjs.com)) Many thanks @Chris!
2. created a file server.js in my root folder;
3. added the following code (see below the listing of server.js) (after reading the documentation and following these two links: [HelloDimitri on Heroku stack](https://hellodmitri.com/index.php/2015/12/12/herokustatic/); [Zurb Foundation deployment on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799254/foundation-sites-deploy-to-heroku);
4. had to reconfigure my server.js because of the paths expressjs needed had to be according to my project;
5. created a procfile in my root folder for Heroku to use yarn instead of npm(uses npm if no profile is there);
6. updated my gulpfile.babel.js to simply build the app and not start any server;
7. updated my package.json and added expressjs in the dependencies;
8. updated my package.json and added the start script for node to start the server as per server.js;
9. after all that, I ran `yarn start` locally and it all went well;
10. pushed the changes to my GitHub repo and deployed on Heroku.

and that's it.

I hope this helps people with the same issue. Many thanks to @Chris. 
cheers.

package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp && node server.js",
    "build": "gulp build --production"   }
```

package.json dependencies (I have the same as devDependencies. still don't know if I need them or not for the build on Heroku. Will update once I find out.):

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "motion-ui": "^2.0.3",
    "what-input": "^5.1.2",
     "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.1.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.3.1",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.7.0",
    "gulp-extname": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.7.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.4.6",
    "panini": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "style-sherpa": "^1.0.0",
    "uncss": "^0.16.2",
    "vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.1.1",
    "yargs": "^12.0.2"
  }
```

gulpfile.babel.js

```
gulp.task('default',gulp.series('build'));
```

Profile

```
web: yarn start
```

server.js code:

```
// server.js

var express = require('express')
var app = express()


app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))


app.use(express.static('dist',{
    index: false, 
    immutable: true, 
    cacheControl: true,
    maxAge: "30d"
}));

// app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'))
console.log("dirname "+__dirname)
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    console.log('request: '+request)
                      response.sendFile(__dirname+'/dist/index.html')
                    })

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
                      console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
                    })
```